# How to create an In app media storage using Ionic on iOS?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic-native

How to create an In app media storage using Ionic on iOS? Just like whatsapp does.

When we download media files on whatsapp on iOS, it creates its own space for storing files. Is it possible to create such storage using Ionic on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

- For Ionic 2/3, you can use the `@ionic-native` plugins `file` and `file transfer` to relaize that.

  [Here](https://github.com/dsgriffin/ionic-3-file-transfer-example) is a good example on how to do it.
- For older versions Ionic 1.x, you can use [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/store-camera-photos-permanently-using-phonegap-ionic-ngcordova/) tutorial.

Comment: I added a tutorial for older versions aswell